# How to get the mp3 link duration when playing in vlc python?

Tags: python, urllib, vlc, audio-player, mutagen

I was trying to play music from music stored in Firebase Storage using vlc packages. However, when using this packages, we need to define the duration of the time sleep. Error occured when I used **urllib.request** and **mutagen** library to retrieve it.

**Error**

> ```
> can't sync to MPEG frame
> ```

```
      try:
                    filename, headers = urlretrieve(musicURL)
                    audio = MP3(filename)
                    print(audio.info.length)
                    self.mediaPlayer = vlc.MediaPlayer(musicURL)
                    self.mediaPlayer.play()
                    time.sleep(180)
                    print("Music " + musicName + " is playing")
                    # I not yet find ways to determine music duration from url
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    pass
```

Comment: Can't you call [`vlc.MediaPlayer.get_length()`](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.MediaPlayer-class.html#get_length)?

Comment: I was getting this error ```types.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'AttributeError'>: 'str' object has no attribute '_as_parameter_'```

Comment: For what call? Start playing the track, then ask VLC for its length, then sleep for that time?

Comment: ```musicLength = vlc.MediaPlayer.get_length(musicURL)
                        print(musicLength)``` this is the call I made. and I put in musicLength into time.sleep oso same error

Comment: Yeah, that's not what I meant. Read the linked documentation.

Comment: Hi thanks for the tips I just manage to get it, coz I need to do automation whereby there will be different duration for every different music URL but I manage to think about the logic and the syntax. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

So, from the comments: instead of trying to use Mutagen, just ask VLC for the duration.

```
self.mediaPlayer = vlc.MediaPlayer(musicURL)
self.mediaPlayer.play()
duration = self.mediaPlayer.get_length()
print(f"Playing {musicName}")
time.sleep(duration / 1000)  # duration is in milliseconds
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help but actually this version of code didnt work out so I have updated my answer too

Comment: @Wesley So the only difference is that you wait for a moment before getting the length? :)

Comment: ya coz somehow if I didnt wait. It will just directly stop there with ````mp4 demux: Fragment sequence discontinuity detected 1 != 0```` So I wait for few second to get the length then replay again

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification, I have managed to solve the problem and below is my code:

```
try:
    self.mediaPlayer = vlc.MediaPlayer(musicURL)
    self.mediaPlayer.play()
    time.sleep(3)
    duration = self.mediaPlayer.get_length()
    self.musicLength = duration/1000

except:
    pass
                        
print(self.musicLength)
self.mediaPlayer.play()
time.sleep(self.musicLength)
print("Music " + musicName + " is playing")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a different approach/implementation where you can use VLC but *don't have to call `media_player.play()`*. It isn't asynchronous, but it is almost instant anyway.

```
def get_audio_duration(audio_path):
    # Get audio duration in ms using vlc
    # Works with vlc.__version__ 3.0.1812

    # audio_path: <str> path to an audio file
    # return: <int> audio duration in ms

    media = vlc.Media(audio_path)
    media_player = vlc.MediaPlayer()
    media_player.set_media(media)

    media.parse_with_options(1, 0)
    while media.get_duration() < 0:
        continue
    
    return media.get_duration()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).