# I need a method to obtain a video file duration in vlc

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, vlc, python-vlc

I am developing a headless application on a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W, Bullseye OS, and using `VLC` (Python) to view video files (h264).  I have loaded `vlc` and `python-vlc`.  I am able to view videos using the play/stop commands, but have to put a timer in between the commands, because I don't know the actual length of the videos.

I have seen get_length() used in a couple of online `vlc` examples, but I get an error on my system.

```
    AttributeError: 'MediaListPlayer' object has no attribute 'get_length'
```

Here is my relevant code:

```
video_file = '/var/tmp/video.h264'

instance = vlc.Instance("--verbose=0","--no-xlib","--vout=mmal_vout")
media_list = instance.media_list_new([video_file])
list_player = instance.media_list_player_new()
list_player.set_media_list(media_list)

duration = list_player.get_length()            # Without this line, the video plays

list_player.play()
time.sleep(TriggerOnTime.seconds + (TriggerOnTime.microseconds / 1000000) + 1)
list_player.stop()
```

What am I missing?

I expect to load a time in "duration".

Comment: "*I have seen get_length() used in a couple of online vlc examples*" You probably saw it used on an instance of a [`MediaPlayer`](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.MediaPlayer-class.html#get_length) not a [`MediaListPlayer`](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.MediaListPlayer-class.html) instance.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73617313/1256347

Comment: For what I could understand from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-vlc-mediaplayer-getting-length-of-current-media/) you need to play the video at least for a bit to be able to get it's lenght

Comment: I changed my code to use media_player instead of media_player_list and at least I could call get_length().  The video would play, but I did not get a valid duration.  

 - If I called get_length() before playing the video, it returned a "-1".  
 - If I play for 500 mS and then stop and call get_length(), it returns a "0".

The actual length of the video was 3.524 seconds.

Comment: I have even tried:

    video = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)

    duration = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
    frame_count = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)

But, I still get zero length and frame count of -230584300921369.0

Is it because h264 does not embed such information?

Comment: To get the duration, you need to start playing the video or `parse` it. See here for more details and links for using the `eventmanager`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55530219/get-the-duration-of-a-url-based-media-object-with-python-vlc-cannot-parse

Comment: Or you could cheat and use `ffprobe` e.g. `ffprobe -i volume.mp4 -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" -sexagesimal` - 0:01:32.857000
or `ffprobe -i volume.mp4 -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"` -
92.857000